# Passing a url in a form from page to servlet drops part of query string

Tags: html, jsp, url

If I have a form on a JSP like this:

```
<form action = "/myApp/myServlet?rssFeedURL=${rssFeedURL}' />" method = "post">
    <input type = "button" value = "See data for this RSS feed."/>
</form>
```

What I find is that if the variable ${rssFeedURL} has no query string, then the server receives it properly, e.g.:

```
http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml
```

But if a query string exists, e.g.:

```
http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=m&output=rss
```

I expect that it is to do with the encoding of the '&' character. Can anyone advise?

The server receives only:

```
http://news.google.com/news?ned=us
```

My pages are charset=UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL-encode request parameters. Otherwise they will be interpreted as part of the initial request URL.

JSTL offers you the `<c:url>` for this.

```
<c:url var="formActionURL" value="/myApp/myServlet">
    <c:param name="rssFeedURL" value="${rssFeedURL}" />
</c:url>

<form action= "${formActionURL}" method="post">
    ...
```

An alternative is to create an EL function which delegates to [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).